# "Error running git [init /workspace/output/]: exit status 1\n/workspace/output/.git: Permission denied\n"

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have the below tekton pipeline, and trying to run on Google Cloud

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: ft-common-run
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: ft-common
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-common-pvc
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      value: docker.io/library/gradle:jdk17-alpine@sha256:e80d3108c319eaeef966eefdfd075fdaa44201c8fb6730532a16555426c61dbd
  taskRunSpecs:
    - pipelineTaskName: git-clone
      taskServiceAccountName: git-service-account
    - pipelineTaskName: clean-build-publish
      taskServiceAccountName: gcp-service-account
```

**Cluster role binding**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: file-system-access-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gcp-service-account
    namespace: fetebird-tekton
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: git-service-account
    namespace: fetebird-tekton
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: file-system-access
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

**Cluster Role**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: file-system-access
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs: ["get", "list", "exec"]
```

The service account has below permission

[image]

**Exception**

```
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063826871Z + '[' false '=' true ]
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063928558Z + '[' false '=' true ]
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063935807Z + '[' false '=' true ]
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063941856Z + CHECKOUT_DIR=/workspace/output/
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063948512Z + '[' true '=' true ]
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063953410Z + cleandir
2023-09-08T12:10:24.063959000Z + '[' -d /workspace/output/ ]
2023-09-08T12:10:24.066654147Z + rm -rf /workspace/output//lost+found
2023-09-08T12:10:24.067843454Z + rm -rf '/workspace/output//.[!.]*'
2023-09-08T12:10:24.069011915Z + rm -rf '/workspace/output//..?*'
2023-09-08T12:10:24.069880010Z + test -z 
2023-09-08T12:10:24.069945026Z + test -z 
2023-09-08T12:10:24.069953496Z + test -z 
2023-09-08T12:10:24.069960028Z + git config --global --add safe.directory /workspace/output
2023-09-08T12:10:24.071523325Z + /ko-app/git-init '-url=git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git' '-revision=' '-refspec=' '-path=/workspace/output/' '-sslVerify=true' '-submodules=true' '-depth=1' '-sparseCheckoutDirectories='
2023-09-08T12:10:24.090957316Z {"level":"error","ts":1694175024.0906546,"caller":"git/git.go:53","msg":"Error running git [init /workspace/output/]: exit status 1\n/workspace/output/.git: Permission denied\n","stacktrace":"github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.run\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:53\ngithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.Fetch\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:88\nmain.main\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init/main.go:53\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250"}
2023-09-08T12:10:24.091295150Z {"level":"fatal","ts":1694175024.0911646,"caller":"git-init/main.go:54","msg":"Error fetching git repository: exit status 1","stacktrace":"main.main\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init/main.go:54\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250"}
```

Not sure what permission do I need to set for service account.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing, adding below code to the pipeline-run solve the issue

```
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
```

**Pipeline-run**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: ft-common-run
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: ft-common
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
```